# python+mysql making the code work every minutes

Tags: python, mysql

```
database.
dbConn = MySQLdb.connect("localhost","database_username","password","database_name") or die ("could not connect to database")

cursor = dbConn.cursor()

device = '/dev/tty.usbmodem1411' #this will have to be changed to the serial port you are using
try:
  print "Trying...",device 
  arduino = serial.Serial(device, 9600) 
except: 
  print "Failed to connect on",device    

try: 
  data = arduino.readline()  
  pieces = data.split("\t")  

try:
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO weatherData (humidity,tempC) VALUES (%s,%s)", (pieces[0],pieces[1]))
    dbConn.commit() #commit the insert
    cursor.close()  #close the cursor
except MySQLdb.IntegrityError:
    print "failed to insert data"
finally:
    cursor.close()  #close just incase it failed
except:
    print "Failed to get data from Arduino!"
```

hello 
i'm having trouble making it work every like minutes 
i want it to work in the code not like crontab
and one more the code insert data into mysqldb and i dont want the data limitless growing i want to make it work automatically erase the data that is over like thousand or data that is over a week

Comment: Please correct the identation of your code. What exactly are you trying to do? Would you like to run this script every `n` minutes?

Comment: i want to run this code every n minutes or just run the code where insert into is i want it to input data into the db every n minutes automatically

Answer (score 0):

If your only goal is to run that code every `n` minutes and you don't want to use [Cron](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto) (**which you totally should**) this is a simple solution which has some drawbacks:

```
from time import sleep

sleep_for_n_minutes = 1

while True:
    # Your code goes here

    # Sleep for n minutes (sleep takes seconds -> multiply by 60)
    sleep(sleep_for_n_minutes * 60)
```

If you run this in the background you need to kill the process using tools your operating system provides. If you reboot your device you will need to start the script manually (or automate it in some way).

This solves the problem, but you should **really** use Cron for stuff like that.